# PHP Exec Not running, but command works ok!

Tags: php

I have the following script to take an uploaded PDF in PHP and call ImageMagik/Ghostscript to convert to images of specified size.

```
$tmp = exec("convert \"{$strPDF}\" -resize 500X500 \"{$strOut}\"", $results);
```

However, this doesnt seem to work. No errors in the log file and no errors on screen. If I do the following,

```
$tmp = exec("convert \"{$strPDF}\" -resize 500X500 \"{$strOut}\"", $results); 
echo ("convert \"{$strPDF}\" -resize 500X500 \"{$strOut}\"");
```

And I paste the output into a command prompt it works fine (It takes around 6-10 seconds - My max_execution_time is at 600.

Any suggestions on why this might not be working?

This is Windows, IIS 7 and PHP5.

Edit: I'm having the same issue in both CentOS and Windows. Both have ImageMagik and Ghostscript installed.

Edit Edit the below still fails.

```
$handle = popen("convert \"{$strPDF}\" -resize 500X500 \"{$strOut}\"","r");
        echo "'$handle'; " . gettype($handle) . "\n";
        $read = fread($handle, 2096);
        echo $read;
        pclose($handle);
```

Comment: You are asking for trouble by putting variables directly in the command line. **CLI Injection** is as dangerous, if not more dangerous than *SQL Injection*. Use [`escapeshellarg()`](http://php.net/escapeshellarg).

Comment: @Andrew Comment noted, thanks.

Comment: Try using popen instead of exec and read the output (with fgets)

Comment: @Milan Babuškov Same issue. :( Updated main post with code.

Comment: Does $strPDF or $strOut contain spaces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in php.ini maybe this function exec declare under

```
disable_functions
```

or if you run in

> safe mode

This function is disabled when PHP is running in [safe mode](http://il2.php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php).

Comment: (safe_mode = Off and disable_functions = ) So doesnt look like it is that.

Comment: maybe permission on this file or this directory

Answer (score 10):

Try adding 2>&1 to the end of your command. I found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17914402/php-exec-is-not-executing-the-command).

```
exec('some_command 2>&1', $output);
print_r($output);  // to see the respond to your command
```

Answer (score 1):

Could it be an issue with your PATH variable ?

You might want to try and run

```
<?php
echo exec('cmd.exe /c echo %path%');
?>
```

both in the command line and from IIS and compare their outputs.

Comment: Might help if you try using absolute paths in this case (especially if even "cmd.exe" does not execute).