# php exec() is not executing the command

Tags: php, windows, exec

I have tried to use `exec()` with `'whoami'` to check if it works and I got the result of

```
nt authority\system
```

Now I need to run a `.exe` file with parameters from `php` via `exec()` function.

I tried this in **command prompt** and it actually runs the program with given parameters. This is the example command.

**NOTE** the exe file gets 3 inputs (folder, file_name, report_file_nmae)

```
> ..\..\some_file.exe folder="C:\path_to_folder" param=1.xml report=2.xml
```

But when I run this command from `php` file:

```
exec('..\..\some_file.exe folder="C:\path_to_folder" param=1.xml report=2.xml');
```

nothing is happening. This is the first time I am using exec() function, so I am not familiar with its details. ***What is wrong?***

I tried using:

- `\\` instead of `\`
- `escapeshellarg()` on the directory
- added `""` around directory folder names

No luck

**Addendum:**

```
echo exec($command)  // echos < .... why?
```

or

```
exec($command, $output);
print_r($output);        // Array()
```

I even changed the permission on the file to full control to all users.
If I call the program from `command prompt`, I can see the icon appearing next to clock for a second.

But the same call from `php` will not even call the program.

**Edit**

Even `exec('notepad.exe');` is not working. Something has to be done with `php` configurations maybe?

Comment: Make sure PHP has permission to excecute that file.

Comment: how can i make sure.....

Comment: I honestly do not know how to do that in Windows since it's permission system is real inconsistent.

Comment: what's the `..\..\some_dir` in the beginning for ?

Comment: Have you tried getting the output from `exec()`? Try something like `$out = array(); exec('your_command 2>&1',$out);`; although the `2>&1` is a linux thing.

Comment: Yes, it gives me `<`....why?

Comment: @alfasin did not get you question

Comment: You need the complete output, not only the last line. See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php ... This means you have to have an array like in my example.

Comment: @A.S.Roma my question is regarding the syntax of the command: it looks like: `relative-path-to-folder<space>full-path\file.exe...` and I don't get what the first part is for - how does it work from command-prompt ?

Comment: Oh, I see, that was a typo, I EDITED...tnx

Comment: Break this problem down a bit.  If you specify the full path to the EXE, does it work?  If you allow any user on the system to execute, does it work?

Comment: but if from command prompt it works without full path, do you thing that is the reason? Because the .exe is relative from that path to php file that calls the exec()... What do you want me to add...just tell me

Comment: @Brad No, full path did not change anything.

Comment: Yes, that you could be the reason because the server user executes from another folder!

Answer (score 120, accepted):

I already said that I was new to `exec()` function. After doing some more digging, I came upon `2>&1` which needs to be added at the end of command in `exec()`.

Thanks `@mattosmat` for pointing it out in the comments too. I did not try this at once because you said it is a Linux command, I am on Windows.

So, what I have discovered, the command is actually executing in the back-end. That is why I could not see it actually running, which I was expecting to happen.

For all of you, who had similar problem, my advise is to use that command. **It will point out all the errors and also tell you info/details about execution.**

```
exec('some_command 2>&1', $output);
print_r($output);  // to see the response to your command
```

Thanks for all the help guys, I appreciate it ;)

Comment: Knowing this helped a lot.  Couldn't figure out why I wasn't getting my response back.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it helped a lot. and I got a result as "Access is Denied" on PHP on IIS.
So I have added permission for NEWTWORK USER  to the file I was executing.

Comment: If you're running XAMPP checkout this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24941078/ffmpeg-and-php-on-mac-doest-work

Comment: Adding 2>&1 helped me as well. can someone explain what does it mean?

Comment: @DipuRaj I have the same problem, where did you added those permissions? directly on the server or in PHP? I need your help please.

Comment: @RakeshK - The '2>&1' is for redirecting errors to the standard IO. And the most important thing is the '&' at the end of the command string, which tells the terminal not to wait for a response.

Comment: i am getting error "perable program or batch file" while i use above syntax even simple command ipconfig too.

Comment: @ßãlãjî what is your PHP version? And can you write the PHP code here exactly the way you do to get the message?

Answer (score 0):

You might also try giving the full path to the binary you're trying to run. That solved my problem when trying to use `ImageMagick`.