# Can't run script using PHP's exec(), possible permissions problems

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, permissions, openai-whisper

I'm having trouble executing a command using PHP's `exec` function.  I think there are two different permissions (or maybe environment?) problems.

In this case, the script I'm having trouble with is `whisper` (OpenAI's Whisper).  The setup is Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS, Apache 2.4.52, PHP 8.1.5.

PHP runs the `exec` function as the web server user `www-data`.  (I have confirmed this with an `exec('whoami')`.)

Whisper was installed using `pip` under my regular username, which I'll call `myrealusername`.

In my command prompt under my regular username, if I type `whereis whisper`, I get the answer `whisper: /home/myrealusername/.local/bin/whisper`.  If, however, I try `sudo -u www-data whereis whisper`, I get the answer `whisper:`, which indicates to me that the web server user `www-data` just can't find Whisper.

The content of `whisper` is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys
from whisper.transcribe import cli
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(cli())
```

The command I'm trying to run using `exec` is `whisper 'mediafilename.mp3' --model tiny --language English > 'outputfilename.txt'`.  (This is a bit simplified; actually, `mediafilename.mp3` and `outputfilename.txt` are specified with respective paths which I won't repeat here; I have ensured that those paths are owned by www-data.)  This same command works perfectly fine to generate the output when run using my regular username `myrealusername`, provided that the input and output are owned by that user name.

When I try running the above command using PHP's `exec` function, `outputfilename.txt` is created as an empty file owned by `www-data` with permissions 0644 (rw-r--r--).  This is true whether Whisper is specified in the command as just `whisper` or as the full path `/home/myrealusername/.local/bin/whisper`.

When I try running the above command using the command prompt (ensuring first that the output file is deleted) as the web server user with `sudo -u www-data whisper 'mediafilename.mp3' --model tiny --language English > 'outputfilename.txt'`, I get `outputfilename.txt: Permission denied`, and the output file is *not* created.  This is true whether I specify Whisper as just `whisper` or as `/home/myrealusername/.local/bin/whisper`.

However, if the output file is created and its permissions are manually changed to rw-r--rw- using `sudo chmod 0646 outputfilename.txt`, so that the output file is writeable by all, then, in the command line, `sudo -u www-data whisper 'mediafilename.mp3' --model tiny --language English > 'outputfilename.txt'` gives the error `whisper: command not found` and `sudo -u www-data /home/myrealusername/.local/bin/whisper 'mediafilename.mp3' --model tiny --language English > 'outputfilename.txt'` gives the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/myrealusername/.local/bin/whisper", line 5, in <module>
    from whisper.transcribe import cli
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'whisper'
```

So, I think I might be having two separate problems.  First, although PHP is able to create the output text file `outputfilename.txt`, it doesn't have the proper permissions to write to it via the `whisper` command.  (It's strange to me that `www-data` can't even *create* the output file from the command line, whereas PHP somehow can create an (empty) output file, but I'm not sure what to make of that.)  Second, I think PHP (i.e., the www-data user) isn't able to find or run the `whisper` command.

Please, if you have any thoughts or solutions, I would be much obliged.

**EDIT:** I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25669221/php-exec-function-not-executing-my-compiled-program-permissions-related?rq=2) with an answer by mz3 suggesting that `www-data` cannot read/write/execute anything outside the directories set up in the Apache configuration files.  How can I modify my .conf file so that `www-data` can execute `whisper`, without letting outside traffic into those parts of my filesystem?  Would something like the following work?

```
  <Directory /home/myrealusername/.local/bin>
    Options ExecCGI
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
    <Files "whisper">
      Require all granted
      SetHandler cgi-script
    </Files>
  </Directory>
```

Comment: This sounds to me like the binary is not on the path home/myrealusername/.local/bin/whisper works for your local user. As it's in their local bin. If won't work for www-data as how would www-data know to look there. If multiple users use it. Then put it in a more standard place

Comment: @exussum Based on this it seems that /home/myrealusername/.local/bin is how the pip package manager likes to organize things.  How can I clear this up without messing with what the package manager likes to see?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30274743/what-is-the-purpose-of-home-local

Comment: Sudo the pip install. That will make it global

Comment: @exussum After `sudo pip install openai-whisper` when I try to execute the whisper command using `sudo -u www-data`, I get `Permission denied: '/var/www/.cache'`, which is not a file or folder that exists. Solved this with `sudo mkdir /var/www/.cache; sudo chgrp www-data /var/www/.cache; sudo chmod g+w /var/www/.cache`.  But I still get `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: './outputfilename.txt'` after Whisper has done its processing, no matter whether or not outputfilename.txt has been created and assigned www-data as its owner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran into the same issue, spent ours on it, very frustrating.
In the end, I even chmod'ed the directory to 777 and still got the same error.

What finally did it for me was to include the file type and directory in the whisper command, with the `--output_format` and `--output_dir` options.
So, to be clear,

```
exec("whisper /dirname/filename.mp3");
```

... gave me the permission denied error, but

```
exec("whisper /dirname/filename.mp3 --output_format srt --output_dir /dirname");
```

... worked without a glitch, no idea why.

Comment: Thanks.  I solved my problem but I tried so many combinations of things it was impossible to tell what exactly was the solution.  I know that in the end I got it working using both the terminal output to file (`> /path/output.txt`) as well as the command line output (`-f txt -o /path/`).  I will mark your answer as correct, but allowing that there may be more to do in terms of assuring that permissions are set with `chown` and `chmod`, either using command line commands or using PHP's built-in commands.