# Whisper on Apple Silicon Mac. zsh: permission denied after force-quitting python?

Tags: terminal, homebrew, apple-silicon, macos-ventura, openai-whisper

I am using Whisper from the terminal of an apple silicon mac and installed it following [these instructions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ldD1m_fg-3c) (installing homebrew and then ffmpeg). I have been using it from the terminal and it has been working fine for days. However, yesterday I force-quitted the python process from the activity monitor app while it was transcribing (something I had done once before with no repercussions) and, since then, I get a permission denied error (zsh: permission denied) when trying to transcribe files. Things I have tried:

- Giving full disk access to terminal
- Changing permissions of the audio file through the "get info" menu(everyone allowed to read and write)
- Granted permission to execute the file through the terminal (`chmod +x`) - when I do this the permission denied error goes away, but then I get an exec format error (zsh: exec format error: filename), as if the format of the file could not be played. However, I can play the file from the terminal by using `afplay` (I can also play the file from terminal when attempting transcription gives a permission denied error)

Today I updated my mac to Ventura 13.5 from Monterey and now I get a bad interpreter error (zsh: /Users/Username/whisper/venv/bin/whisper: bad interpreter: /Users/Username/whisper/venv/bin/python3: no such file or directory) but python3 is in that folder. I tried to solve this as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76144273/cant-run-script-using-phps-exec-possible-permissions-problems/76191615#76191615), by specifying `--output_format` and `--output_dir` and it seems to work for the bad interpreter error, but then it goes back to the permission denied error.

Any idea about what may be happening and how to go about it?