# exec() not runs on background process in php

Tags: php, php-7.3

I am trying to run bgprocess.php in background and want to save output in backgroundOutput.php

```
exec("php bgprocess.php > backgroundOutput.php 2>&1 & echo $!", $commandOutput);
```

But its not showing any error on $commandOurput and not run bgprocess.php as well.

Its works : `exec("php bgprocess.php", $commandOutput);`

and also works from terminal command line.

tried following possible way to solve issue by reference :

- [php exec() background process issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14555971/php-exec-background-process-issues)
- [PHP Exec Not running, but command works ok!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652263/php-exec-not-running-but-command-works-ok)
- nohup bgprocess.php > backgroundOutput.php 2>&1 & echo $!

Comment: is this a process that have a start and end or is a server type process that is going to live forever ?

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding something, you can't have a background process _and_ "output something", it is either one or the other. Your background process itself can write to disk/database/whatever, but the foreground that is responsible for kicking off the background process will continue on and never receive the output (unless you put a looping sleep lock but that would defeat the purpose of a background process). So basically I think you need to write to `/dev/null` as those other posts say. If you need to capture anything, that logic needs to be in `backgroundOutput.php` or a wrapper

Comment: @ChrisHaas i have tried /dev/null still not run bgprocess.php code in background by exec().l just need to run bgprocess.php in background.if have simple <?php echo 'Hello'; ?> in bgprocess.php then 'Hello' want to print in backgroundOutput.php.Hopes you understand..